# Responsive overflow option tabs

Tags: reactjs, tabs, less, responsive

How to implement adding a gradient to the beginning and end of tabs for the mobile version in react (as in the photo)? Additional tabs are implied by a dark-to-light color gradient on the tab label overhang. This color gradient provides the user with a visual signal that a horizontal swipe-to-scroll interaction will reveal additional tabs.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxh98.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by mobile version of react, you mean react native. If that's the case and you are using expo, you can use expo's linear gradient (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/linear-gradient/) and absolutely position a gradient on the right of the row of tabs to have the desired effect. If you meant you just wanted a mobile web display, you can use a regular div and set the background color to a linear gradient instead.